# '::main' must return 'int' void main() ^

Tags: visual-c++

I was just testing visual code for c++ and it's constantly showing me this error in spite of changing void and int that too in a basic "hello world" programme.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you are compiling a different file than you show us.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.